# How to publish a TypeScript based npm module that contains CSS modules?

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, css-modules

I am developing an in-house TypeScript based library for shared react components. The build process is simply `tsc` only followed by publishing to internal npm registry. There isn't a need of complicated Babel compilation process since the build artifacts are used within the team only and proper transpilation is run on this library when the consuming applications run their Webpack bundling process.

Problems started to occur when I tried to break one single `styles.css` file into properly split [CSS modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/). To use CSS modules, there will be code syntax like below in my React component files. e.g. in `FooComponent.tsx`,

```
import 'FooComponent.css';
```

TypeScript compiler doesn't understand it fully hence it would just put the same import statement in the compiled `FooComponent.js` file. Now the question is how should I bundle and distribute these separate CSS modules? I know that Webpack has plugins like [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) to handle CSS modules once they are properly loaded. But I am thinking what's the best way to distribute these CSS modules in my setup.

Since the consuming applications have their full setup on Webpack to properly load and bundle JS/CSS assets, the easiest solution I can think of is just to attach those CSS modules accordingly in the `dist` folder where TypeScript compilation results are stored, to ensure that those import statements on CSS files won't end up into resource not found. If I bundle the CSS modules in some other way during the build process, those import statements need to be either removed or specially handled, something like what [gulp-csslit](https://github.com/kcmr/gulp-csslit#readme) does to convert CSS files to JS files.

I haven't experimented on any of that yet but would like to know best practices if anyone could shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Since the consuming applications process and bundle CSS assets on their own, I found the easiest way is to simply put the CSS modules into the `dist` folder. For that I use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/).